# AppEngine app property not populating url

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

Followed the tutorial and my CloudSqlServlet.java init() function:

```
   try {
        ApiProxy.Environment env = ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment();
        Map<String, Object> attr = env.getAttributes();
    String hostname = (String) attr.get("com.google.appengine.runtime.default_version_hostname");

    String url = hostname.contains("localhost:")
            ? System.getProperty("cloudsql-local") : System.getProperty("cloudsql");
    log("connecting to: " + url);
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new ServletException("Unable to connect to Cloud SQL", e);
    }
```

This is my appegnine-web.xml:

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <version>1</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  <runtime>java8</runtime>

  <use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>

  <service>cloudsql</service>

  <system-properties>
    <property name="cloudsql" value="jdbc:google:mysql://${INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}/${database}?user=${user}&amp;password=${password}" />
    <property name="cloudsql-local" value="jdbc:mysql://google/${database}?useSSL=false&amp;cloudSqlInstance=${INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}&amp;socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&amp;user=${user}&amp;password=${password}" />
  </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

The app compiles with maven. I then run the appengine server in one terminal:

```
mvn appengine:run
```

And in another terminal I'll run the sql proxy:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=skeleton-182342:europe-west1:trial1131=tcp:3306
```

Then when I access the server locally: `localhost:8080/cloudsql`
The app throws an exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Cloud SQL
>   instance [${INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}], expected value in form
>   [project:region:name].

And in the logs I can see that the properties are not inserted into the url:

```
log: CloudSQL: connecting to: jdbc:mysql://google/${database}?useSSL=false&cloudSqlInstance=${INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&user=${user}&password=${password}
```

Answer (score 0):

As for your code, everything looks fine except for the ending in the line saying `</system-properties>mv`, where you may have a typo in `mv`.

Maybe this is the tutorial you were talking about, but in any case I recommend you to have a look at the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/cloud-sql/) for connecting a Java App Engine application to Cloud SQL.

For what I see, I think you may not have changed the app properties for your application with the appropriate values, and maybe you have the default ones. You can change them in the `pom.xml` file, which should look like the following (additional information [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/cloud-sql/#setting-up) too):

```
<properties>
    <INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>PROJECT:REGION:INSTANCE</INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>
    <user>USER</user>
    <password>PASSWORD</password>
    <database>DB_NAME</database>

    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>
```

Your application will be retrieving the properties from that file, so make sure to update your properties with the corresponding values.